# How to select some column in huge table which contain null data in some row and use distinict in column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, actionresult

I have huge table which contains some column null data but I don't want to change anything in table.
In one of my view I want to select just two column to display in the page, first is ID and second is Area but in Area, I should use distinct and prevent to display null value
there is my code but it not work and tell me how can I do it.

```
public class ClsArea
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string AreaName { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
        {


            return View(DB.school.ToList());
        }

----------



@model IEnumerable<school.Models.ClsArea>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <select class="form-control">
                @foreach (var itemArea in Model.Select(c => new { c.IdSMP, c.Area }).ToList() as IEnumerable<ClsArea>)
                {

                        <option value=@itemArea.id>
                            @itemArea.areaname
                        </option>

                }
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Error Display

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[PMIS_V01.Models.ClsArea]'.
```

Comment: In which line you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Distinct` will not prevent `NULL` values. It was not designed to do so. It will pull one `NULL` value with others.

If you want to skip the `NULL` values then why don't you just ignore those? Something like:

```
DB.school.where(s => s.Area != null).ToList()
```

**Update:**

You are expecting list of `school.Models.ClsArea` in the view but you are sending list of `DB.school` type from action. `DB.school` is the entity model type right?

Comment: my problam not to prevent Null my problam is error (System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[PMIS_V01.Models.ClsArea]'.)

Comment: idont want to send all data to decress speeding load of my page

Comment: You are already sending all the data. There is no paging in your code. However my updated answer was not about data volume. The error you are having is due to the parameter mismatch.